# MATLAB to Python Conversion Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I have some code in MATLAB that I'm trying to convert into python.  I know very little about python, so this is turning out to be a bit of a challenge.

Here's the MATLAB code:

```
xm_row = -(Nx-1)/2.0+0.5:(Nx-1)/2.0-0.5;
xm = xm_row(ones(Ny-1, 1), :);
ym_col = (-(Ny-1)/2.0+0.5:(Ny-1)/2.0-0.5)';  
ym = ym_col(:,ones(Nx-1,1));
```

And here is my very rough attempt at trying to do the same thing in python:

```
 for x in range (L-1):
     for y in range (L-1):
         xm_row = x[((x-1)/2.0+0.5):((x-1)/2.0-.5)]
         xm = xm_row[(ones(y-1,1)),:]
         ym_column = transposey[(-(y-1)/2.0+0.5):((y-1)/2.0-.5)]
         ym = ym_column[:,ones(x-1,1)]
```

In my python code, L is the size of the array I am looping across.
When I try to run it in python, I get there error:

```
 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

at the line:

```
 xm_row = x[((x-1)/2.0+0.5):((x-1)/2.0-.5)]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `x` is integer - first value from list `0..L-1`

Comment: `x[ ... ]` - this way you expect that `x` is a list (array) but `x` is single number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, you can implement that in a simpler way with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), like so -

```
Nx = 5;
Ny = 7;

xm_row = -(Nx-1)/2.0+0.5:(Nx-1)/2.0-0.5;
ym_col = (-(Ny-1)/2.0+0.5:(Ny-1)/2.0-0.5)';  
[xm_out,ym_out] = meshgrid(xm_row,ym_col)
```

Let's compare this meshgrid version with the original code for verification -

```
>> Nx = 5;
>> Ny = 7;
>> xm_row = -(Nx-1)/2.0+0.5:(Nx-1)/2.0-0.5;
>> ym_col = (-(Ny-1)/2.0+0.5:(Ny-1)/2.0-0.5)'; 
>> xm = xm_row(ones(Ny-1, 1), :)
xm =
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
>> ym = ym_col(:,ones(Nx-1,1))
ym =
         -2.5         -2.5         -2.5         -2.5
         -1.5         -1.5         -1.5         -1.5
         -0.5         -0.5         -0.5         -0.5
          0.5          0.5          0.5          0.5
          1.5          1.5          1.5          1.5
          2.5          2.5          2.5          2.5
>> [xm_out,ym_out] = meshgrid(xm_row,ym_col)
xm_out =
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
         -1.5         -0.5          0.5          1.5
ym_out =
         -2.5         -2.5         -2.5         -2.5
         -1.5         -1.5         -1.5         -1.5
         -0.5         -0.5         -0.5         -0.5
          0.5          0.5          0.5          0.5
          1.5          1.5          1.5          1.5
          2.5          2.5          2.5          2.5
```

Now, transitioning from MATLAB to Python has a simpler medium in [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/), as it hosts many counterparts from MATLAB for use in a Python environment. For our case, we have a NumPy version of meshgrid and that makes it just a straight-forward porting as listed below -

```
import numpy as np # Import NumPy module

Nx = 5;
Ny = 7;

# Use np.arange that is a colon counterpart in NumPy/Python
xm_row = np.arange(-(Nx-1)/2.0+0.5,(Nx-1)/2.0-0.5+1)
ym_col = np.arange(-(Ny-1)/2.0+0.5,(Ny-1)/2.0-0.5+1)

# Use meshgrid just like in MATLAB
xm,ym = np.meshgrid(xm_row,ym_col)
```

Output -

```
In [28]: xm
Out[28]: 
array([[-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.5]])

In [29]: ym
Out[29]: 
array([[-2.5, -2.5, -2.5, -2.5],
       [-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5],
       [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5],
       [ 2.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5]])
```

Also, please notice that `+1` was being added at the end of the second argument to `np.arange` in both cases, as `np.arange` excludes the second argument element when creating the range of  elements. As an example, if we want to create a range of elements from `3` to `10`, we would be required to do `np.arange(3,10+1)` as shown below -

```
In [32]: np.arange(3,10+1)
Out[32]: array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```